# undefined offset 1 and 2 errors

Tags: php

I am receiving these errors below:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in ... on line 93 
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in ... on line 94
```

What does these errors mean and how can it be fixed? I can't see where the problem is but I know they are appearing after clicking on the "Module Submit" button

$moduleactive = 1;

```
    $sql = "SELECT ModuleId, ModuleNo, ModuleName FROM Module WHERE ModuleActive = ? ORDER BY ModuleNo"; 


     $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

     $sqlstmt->bind_param("i", $moduleactive);

     $sqlstmt->execute(); 

     $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbModuleId,$dbModuleNo,$dbModuleName);


    $moduleHTML  = "";  
      $moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
 $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

     while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
         $moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s_%2$s_%3$s">%1$s - %2$s</option>'.PHP_EOL, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName, $dbModuleId);
    } 

$moduleHTML .= '</select>'; 

    $pHTML = "";


    ?>


<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validation(event);">
<table>
<tr>
<th>Module: <?php echo $moduleHTML; ?></th>
</tr>
</table>
<p><input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Module" name="moduleSubmit" /></p>
<div id="moduleAlert"></div>
<div id="targetdiv"></div>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['moduleSubmit'])) {    

$outputmodule = ""; 

$moduleInfo = explode("_", $_POST['modules']);
$moduleNo = $moduleInfo[0];
$moduleName = $moduleInfo[1]; //Error line 93
$moduleId = $moduleInfo[2]; //Error line 94
$outputmodule = sprintf("<p><strong>Selected Module:</strong> %s - %s <input type='hidden' value='%s'></p>", $moduleNo, $moduleName, $moduleId);

}

?>
```

Comment: `$_POST['modules']` doesn't have enough `_` separated values.

Comment: [You agreed to do thorough research](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) before you could ask this question. How come you did not find the answer in the [7,65 million search results for the Notice](https://www.google.de/search?q=undefined+offset+1+and+2+errors) nor in the [dozens of existing questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Notice+undefined+offset+1+and+2+errors+php)

Comment: Better check nice [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456) first, e.g. this might match: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770836#12770836

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occure because there is no value at that index in $moduleInfo varibale.
As not coming in $_POST['modules'] varible

Replace this to avoid error

```
$moduleName =$moduleInfo[1]; //Error line 93
$moduleId =$moduleInfo[2]; //Error line 94
```

with

```
$moduleName = isset($moduleInfo[1])?$moduleInfo[1]:''; 
$moduleId = isset($moduleInfo[2])?$moduleInfo[2]:'';
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the elements referenced by `1` and `2` are not defined.

You are `explode`ing a string with underscores as posted by the user in `modules`. If that string does not have any (or enough) underscores, `explode` comes back with an array with less elements than you think.

You should validate the input before you use it, and check to see if you actually have at least 3 elements:

```
$moduleInfo = explode("_", $_POST['modules']);
if (count($moduleInfo) >= 3) {
   $moduleNo = $moduleInfo[0];
   $moduleName = $moduleInfo[1]; //Error line 93
   $moduleId = $moduleInfo[2]; //Error line 94

   // validate the subparts (this is important as well!)
} else {
   // set your variables to some sane default or fail gracefully
}
```